# How to get remote file modification time and size from a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing, curl

I have a Linux VPS, There are many HTML forms on it, as follows:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ver</th>
            <th>link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1.0.1</td>
            <td><a href="http://speedtest.tokyo2.linode.com/100MB-tokyo2.bin">download</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.0.2</td>
            <td><a href="http://speedtest.singapore.linode.com/100MB-singapore.bin">download</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.0.3</td>
            <td><a href="http://speedtest.fremont.linode.com/100MB-fremont.bin">download</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.0.4</td>
            <td><a href="http://speedtest.dallas.linode.com/100MB-dallas.bin">download</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.0.5</td>
            <td><a href="http://speedtest.atlanta.linode.com/100MB-atlanta.bin">download</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table is relatively simple, only the version number and file download link.

I want to use a shell script to access the URL in the table, in order to get the remote file date and size, then update this information into the table.

They will eventually look like this:

[image]

Before asking the question, I looked at the curl and wget documentation, where the curl test can view the file information in standard output, but I don't know how to write an automated script to accomplish this task. I just got in touch with Linux, hope can get everyone's help, thank you!

Comment: `lftp`? .......

Comment: You want to use `ssh` to get this information and then comile it to an html file on your local machine? Or are you talking about files hosted on an http server and you are trying to get their modification date without having access to the server?

Comment: read the man page for curl, wget or ssh+ls

Comment: @rudib I have a Linux vps with a number of table files on it. The content format has two columns, the first column is the version number, and the second column is the file download link. I want to run a shell script in Linux that causes the table to display the modification time and size of the download link file. I am a newcomer to Linux. I am not sure if this is feasible?

Comment: @user1133275 Before asking the question, I looked at the curl and wget documentation, where the curl test can view the file information in standard output, but I don't know how to write an automated script to accomplish this task. I just got in touch with Linux, can you help me?

Comment: Ok, but where do you want to display that? For you to check it or on a web page? Are you connecting via `ssh` to do that? For me, it's not really clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @rudib thank for your reply. I have a web service on vps that provides static web access. The content of these web pages is an HTML table, and the content of the table is relatively simple, only the version number and the download link. I want to run a shell script on vps to access the download link in the table, use it to get the remote file modification time and size, and then update this information into the form.

Comment: @rudib Sorry, my English is not good, it comes from machine translation.

Comment: So you are hosting the webpage (part of which you posted) and you want to update the modification dates of the files that are linked there?

Comment: @rudib table is an HTML file, It is added to the web page via the <iframe> tag.

I want to use a shell script to access the download link in the table to get the date and size of the file for the download link, and then update this information to a table.

Comment: @rudib This is the final result that I hope to achieve.https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA8Al.png

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to do, I'll update my answer with a script (might take a while until I get to that). Please update your question with that information so that it's more clear.

Comment: @rudib Thank you, I will re-edit the question.

Comment: @rudib I re-edited this question, hope this is a clear description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the file information you can get from the header:

```
curl --head http://speedtest.newark.linode.com/100MB-newark.bin
```

It will return:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 28 Sep 2019 12:47:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 104857600
Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Aug 2019 16:35:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5d4314cd-6400000"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

If that is what you need, you can write a bash script to generate a table/html file with that information.

You can use this in a script like that:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat  << EOF
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ver</th>
            <th>link</th>
            <th>modified</th>
            <th>size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
EOF

$i=1

cat urls.list | while read url
do
        file_info=$(curl -s --head "$url")
        last_modified=$(echo "$file_info" | grep Last-Modified | cut -c16- | tr -d '\r\n')
        content_length=$(echo "$file_info" | grep Content-Length | cut -c17- | tr -d '\r\n')

cat  << EOF
        <tr>
            <td>1.0.$i</td>
            <td><a href="$url">download</a></td>
            <td>$last_modified</td>
            <td>$content_length</td>
        </tr>
EOF
let "i++"
done

cat << EOF
    </tbody>
</table>
EOF
```

You need to create a file called `urls.list` which should conatain one url per line. Like that:

```
http://speedtest.newark.linode.com/100MB-newark.bin
http://speedtest.tokyo2.linode.com/100MB-tokyo2.bin
```

Running the script will produce an output like that:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ver</th>
            <th>link</th>
            <th>modified</th>
            <th>size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1.0.1</td>
            <td><a href="http://speedtest.newark.linode.com/100MB-newark.bin">download</a></td>
            <td>Thu, 01 Aug 2019 16:35:25 GMT</td>
            <td>104857600</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you need a specific version name, you could store that in the list file with a seperator (e.g.: `version name|url`). And would need to adjust the code a bit. Now, it just follows the order of the url list.

Comment: Yes, before I ask questions, I know that I can get the file information like this. The difficulty is that I don't know how to write a shell script. I just got into Linux, can you help me? I will create a test environment VPS, which is posted here.

Comment: Yes, I know what you need now. I will update my answer as soon as I get to it.

Comment: If the version name has no logic, it will throw a runtime error. Can I output an HTML table based on [this raw data text](http://64.52.109.34/raw_date.yml)? I tried to adjust the script and it failed.

Comment: Parsing `YAML` won't work to well in pure bash, you would need a parser for that. If you keep the file so that it has the date entry on top and then the list below and nothing else, it's still possible to parse it in bash (not yaml compliant). However, a list with the syntax like suggested above, would be simpler.

Comment: I found a solution, set the custom delimiter using the [IFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) variable, and then add the [read](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) variable to get the version number text.

Comment: Thank for your answer, this is very helpful for problem solving! Although the shell is not the best solution, it satisfies my simple use scenario.